# Find the distribution of $P(X=x \mid X+Y=t)$ and calculate its expected value.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, conditional-probability, self-learning

So, the given distribution is a discrete $(X,Y)$ vector with the following probability mass function.

$$
\mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y)=\frac{1}{2 n+1} \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
x
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
y
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n \\
x+y
\end{array}\right)} \mathbb{I}_{\{0, \ldots, n\}}(x) \mathbb{I}_{\{0, \ldots, n\}}(y)
$$

For a given $n$. It looks like a joint hypergeometric my intuition says. My approach was to calculating the distribution was:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X=x \mid X+Y=t)&=P(X=x \mid Y=t-x) \\
& =\frac{P(X=x, Y=t-x)}{P(Y=t-x)}
\end{aligned}
$$

And, with those requirements, I just need to calculate $P(Y=y)$ by marginalizing it with respect to $X$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& P(Y=y)=\sum_{x=0}^n P(x=x, y=y)= \\
& =\sum_{x=0}^n \frac{1}{2 n+1} \frac{\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
x
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
y
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n \\
x+y
\end{array}\right)} \cdot I_{\{1, \cdots ,n\}}(y) \\
& =\frac{1}{2 n+1}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
y
\end{array}\right) \cdot I_{\{1, \cdots, n\}}(y) \sum_{x=0}^n \frac{\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
x
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{l}
2 n \\
(x+y)
\end{array}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
But I don't know how to handle the summation. Is there a property for binomial coefficients I'm not aware, or a different approach to reaching the distribution?
In the original question, they mention the formula for the expectation of a hypergeometric, hinting that that is what the conditional distribution boils down to.

Comment: Be careful about capitalisation: $P(X=x\mid X+Y=t) = \dfrac{P(X=x, Y=t-x)}{P(Y=t-X)}$ and $$P(Y=t-X) = \sum_{x=0}^t 
P(X=x, Y=t-x)$$